# Why does my web scraper not convert the URL'S properly from a CSV for downloading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I'm running a scraper that takes all url's from images that it can find from r/dankmemes on reddit and then converting it to a list, lastly it tries to download these files, but for some reason an error occures. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong, I'm new to python.

The trace back error goes back to ("line38"): `urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0],'/Users/CENSORED/Desktop/Instagrammemes/image_' + str(img_count) + ".jpg")`

The Error Message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/CENSORED/Desktop/FirstImages/scraper.py", line 38, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0],'/Users/CENSORED/Desktop/Instagrammemes/image_' + str(img_count) + ".jpg")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 510, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'h'
```

The code that I think is causing the problem:

```
with open('/Users/CENSORED/Desktop/FirstImages/file.csv') as images :
    images = csv.reader(images)
    img_count = 1
    for image in images:
        image = url.strip('\'"')
        urllib.parse.quote(':')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0],'/Users/CENSORED/Desktop/Instagrammemes/image_' + str(img_count) + ".jpg")
        img_count += 1
```

The text file:

```
    ['https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/JkyImC_zyl4XzE_yW-G4KOUTTFB6MRHUR3eEHvrpq64.png', 
'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png', 'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/gold/badges/award-silver-cartoon.png',
 'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png', 
'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png', 
'https://preview.redd.it/i6sdyng7n3h21.jpg?
width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=1abb4b30f2b74f114f2743cf66bf3d0e7f618abf', 
'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png', 
'https://i.redd.it/m9q2841su3h21.jpg', 
'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png', 
'https://i.redd.it/tsp8qpamc3h21.png', 
'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/gold/badges/award-silver-cartoon.png',
 'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png', 
'https://external-preview.redd.it/Ho2XSQOhaHGN3LhkLnPAf2OTkXwtuBTKQ9FXgdumH-I.jpg?
width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=54356f6b63ea9f51953f6a42d6c77fa4bf47df44', 
'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png', 
'https://preview.redd.it/9j8389cno3h21.jpg?
width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=23c0ef3307b8b8ebdc7c4bcc3d16837ad58e460a', 
'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png', 
'https://preview.redd.it/up1ouzug13h21.jpg?
width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=584bb8c90056156c3d2483d6f4b1030f7bf4e27d', 'https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/JkyImC_zyl4XzE_yW-G4KOUTTFB6MRHUR3eEHvrpq64.png',
 'https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_2zmfe/styles/image_widget_3xmxw4p2gqu01.png', 
'https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/aRUO-zIbXgMTDVJOcxKjY8P6rGkakMdyVXn4k1VN-Mk.png', 'https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/iL0Rq5QLIS6xVLwoYKL8na6ZaSa9tILrBbhBlMfjVdI.png', 'https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/9aAIqRjSQwF2C7Xohx1u2Q8nAUqmUsHqdYtAlhQZsgE.png', 
'https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/voAwqXNBDO4JwIODmO4HXXkUJbnVo_mL_bENHeagDNo.png']
```

Comment: The text file looks like a list [url1,url2...]. Are you sure this is the format of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input file (urls.txt) in the code below looks like:

```
["https://i.redd.it/m9q2841su3h21.jpg",
"https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png",
"https://i.redd.it/tsp8qpamc3h21.png"]
```

The code below downloads the images to c:\temp

```
import urllib.request as req
import json

with open('urls.json') as images:
    images = json.load(images)
    for idx, image_url in enumerate(images):
       image_url = image_url.strip()
       file_name = 'c:\\temp\\{}.{}'.format(idx, 
                                            image_url.strip().split('.')[-1])
        print('About to download {} to file {}'.format(image_url, file_name))
        req.urlretrieve(image_url, file_name)
```

Output:

```
About to download https://i.redd.it/m9q2841su3h21.jpg to file c:\temp\0.jpg
About to download https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/renderTimingPixel.png to file c:\temp\1.png
About to download https://i.redd.it/tsp8qpamc3h21.png to file c:\temp\2.png
```

Comment: I dont mean to be a pain, but when I try and run your code I still get the error   raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: ['https>

Comment: which python version you use? I use 3.4. Please add the exact error. I will add few printing in order to help

Comment: thank you so much, I use python 3.7.2, here is the exact error: https://textuploader.com/1557f  and again I really appreciate the help

Comment: I think the problem is in your input file. Can you share it somehow? Look at 'my' file: urls.txt. Is your file is the same as mine? My file is here: https://textuploader.com/15572

Comment: I dont have access to Dropbox. Put it in https://textuploader.com please.

Comment: https://textuploader.com/1557w mine has weird formatting as you can see.

Comment: OK. Replace every single quote (') with double  quote (") in your file and run the modified code above. By doing this your file will be a valid json and the code will load it as json.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I changed my file to a json, made all the necessary changes to the code and get this error: https://textuploader.com/15578

Comment: share your json file please .Also look at my json example above.

Comment: mine has the exact same formatting as yours, https://textuploader.com/15521

Comment: I was able to do json.load() with your data. So please share the current code as well

Comment: The code looks good as well. Who generates this file for you? Is it  the scraper? How do you create it on disk?

Comment: see here for your modified code https://textuploader.com/1552m The main point is to create a json file

Comment: @bladerman why is this causing so many problems?, this time it stopped right at the end of your code with the error:    json.dump(links, outfile)
NameError: name 'outfile' is not defined

Comment: We have 2 options here. Try to make the json work or save the file as a simple txt file... Select the preferred option